# how can i send command to arm to control cameras

Tags: python, flask

[image: send command from browser to arm to control my cameras]

i have a arm ,by this arm i can control my camera to move right,move left,move down,move up
so i want to send command for this arm 
but this arm is in Local Area Network 
so i must design a server in Wide Area Network 
and by this server i can get the command from browser

so i design the server like this:

i send command by http get 
http://ip:port/sendcommand/arm_id=1&camera_id=2&command_type=3&command_value=4

i receive my command by http get 
http://ip:port/receivecommand/arm_id=1

i want to get a json {  arm_id=1,   command_type=2, command_value=3 }

how can i code my program

Answer (score 0):

`requests` is probably the module to use.

```
def sendCommand():
 requests.get('http://ip:port/sendcommand/arm_id=1&camera_id=2&command_type=3&command_value=4')

def getCommand():
    r = requests.get('http://ip:port/receivecommand/arm_id=1')
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.content
    else:
        raise requests.exceptions.ConnectionError('request failed')
```

Comment: i have no 'http://ip:port/sendcommand/arm_id=1&camera_id=2&command_type=3&command_value=4' and 'http://ip:port/receivecommand/arm_id=1',i want to design them by using python flask

Comment: 'http://ip:port/sendcommand/arm_id=1&camera_id=2&command_type=3&command_value=4' and 'http://ip:port/receivecommand/arm_id=1' are the url i should design for my server ,at the same time it should ensure the real time,if i shouldn't design like this,how can i do for it,help me